# Trying to fetch shopify order having the same order name in excel

Tags: python, excel, shopify

Im trying to extract order information for a shopify order having the same order number as in excel file. However the shopify orders are not being correctly extracted.

Im using the following code:

---

```
workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook("D:\\Setups\\test.xlsx")
sheet = workbook.active

for row in sheet.iter_rows(min_row=2, values_only=True):
    order_id = row[0]
    order_name = row[1]
    order_id = str(order_id).lstrip('#')

    # Find order in Shopify by ID
    try:
        order= shopify.Order.find(order_id)
    except:
        print(f"Order with ID {order_id} not found in Shopify")
        continue

    # Check if order name contains order ID
    if order.name and order_id in order.name:
        print(f"Found order {order_id} with name {order.name}")
```

I am getting the following output:
Order with ID 72685 not found in Shopify
Order with ID 65578 not found in Shopify
Order with ID 65612 not found in Shopify

This means that excel is working fine but somehow the order is not being found in shopify however, there is order number 72685 present in shopify.

Please help how can i fix this.

Comment: By making a blanket `try/except`, you're covering up the real exception and hiding useful information from yourself. Here's an answer that describes how better to use `try/except`  https://stackoverflow.com/a/27586978/6030926